# Format date output for existing data in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and have a small database I am working on for education. I have the following query:

```
SELECT ORDERS.ORDERID,
  ORDERS.CUSTOMERID,
  ORDERS.ORDERDATE,
  ORDERS.SHIPDATE
  SELECT FORMAT (ORDERDATE,'MM DD, YYYY HH:MI:SS')
FROM ORDERS
```

But it errors with

ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 3

I am trying to format the output of ORDERDATE,'MM DD, YYYY HH:MI:SS'

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) function is used to convert dates to formatted strings:

```
SELECT ORDERS.ORDERID,
  ORDERS.CUSTOMERID,
  ORDERS.SHIPDATE,
  TO_CHAR (ORDERDATE,'MM DD, YYYY HH:MI:SS')
FROM ORDERS
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you!